# Scraping data not found in the Source Code using Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been trying to scrape the data on this page using scrapy:

http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=carboflex+140+squash+racket&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Acarboflex+140+squash+racket

Viewing the page you'll notice a page link for the "Tecnifibre carboflex 140 basaltex squash Racquet". Analyzing the page source tells me that the xpath to extract the link is under:

```
//li[@id='result_0']
```

However when I run my scraper, it seems to indicate that no such xpath exists.

I've even tried with further parent xpaths and even tried looking for the link after scraping and extracting the entire html source code of the page and can't find it there despite it being present in the source code.

Comment: Hm, I just ran though it with a htmlagility based crawler, and //li[@id='result_0']//a gave 7 <a> where the first link is http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=carboflex+140+squash+racket&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Acarboflex+140+squash+racket which I assume is correct ?